# How to make flex item height of its parent?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, alignment

I have a simple nav type layout using flex to space items with different widths horizontally. The items have lines between but as they different heights because the content had different heights

How can I make the items the height of the parent so all dividing lines go to the top of the parent.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zbEMVd

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.item:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 150px;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-3 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-4 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-5 {
  flex: 1;
}

.item-6 {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item-1">One</div>
  <div class="item item-2">Two Two Two Two Two </div>
  <div class="item item-3">Three Three Three</div>
  <div class="item item-4">Four</div>
  <div class="item item-5">Five</div>
  <div class="item item-6">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove `align-self` from `.item`, and add `display:flex; align-items: flex-end;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `align-self` from `.item`, and add `display:flex; align-items: flex-end;` instead.

```
.item{
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  /* ... */
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZPXVra

Answer (score 0):

Make the `item` element a *reverse-column flexbox* (and remove `align-self: flex-end` from it) to get the effect - see demo below:

```css
* {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.wrap {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

.item {
  /* align-self: flex-end; */
  display: flex; /* ADDED */
  flex-direction: column-reverse; /* ADDED */
  background: #ddd;
}
.item:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-right: 2px solid red;
}

.item-1 {
  width: 150px;
}

.item-2 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-3 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-4 {
  width: 50px;
}

.item-5 {
  flex: 1;
}

.item-6 {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item item-1">One</div>
  <div class="item item-2">Two Two Two Two Two  </div>
  <div class="item item-3">Three Three Three</div>
  <div class="item item-4">Four</div>
  <div class="item item-5">Five</div>
  <div class="item item-6">Six</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @cdmt could you please upvote / accept answer(s) in this question and close the question too, thanks!